# Opening a JPanel form in NetBeans GUI Builder causes strange behavior

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I recently tried to open a JPanel form that I created with NetBeans GUI Builder and NetBeans almost freezes up on me. The design form is an all-gray background, not the usual gray area where I can place components surrounded by a white background. If I click on the Source button and then switch back to Design view, all of the tabs in the editor pane disappear.

Fortunately I am using Git for version control. The last commit of this file was over a week ago. I might have to revert to an earlier version to see where this problem was introduced. In the mean time, does anyone have any idea what could cause this behavior? Is it possible that my .form file is corrupted? The application compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: ... did you possibly touched some of the NB generated code? How complex is the gui? Any chance that your machine is having a difficulties with NB in general?

Comment: @vector Other GUI files load just fine. As for complexity, the panel that is causing problems contains other custom panels I created in a CardLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Netbeans can't load the form due to some internal error.  This can sometimes be fixed by doing a clean & build to clear out any old cached data.

If that doesn't work, you can check out the "message.log" for the error...and yes, I wish it would display it on the screen

Off memory it use to be in "{user.profile}/.Netbeans/{version}/var/log" (I think).  It got moved on Windows under 7.2 to "{user.profile}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\var\log"

Comment: I found the logs, but can't see anything useful. Although, I did find some other interesting, yet unrelated, information.

Comment: @Code-Guru Try closing Netbeans. Delete the `message.log`, restart Netbeans and reload the form.  That "might" help (at least it will give you a clean log)

Comment: Well, after doing that NetBeans gives me an error message, but that was using a clone version of my Git repository. I tried it in my original and now it works just fine. I'm really scratching my head at this one...

Comment: I see a bunch of exceptions thrown in the messages.log now. It looks like my recent NetBeans doesn't like what I'm trying to do in my recently-added AncestorListeners.

Comment: @Code-Guru See, that was easy :P (insert sarcasm)

Comment: \*snickers\* Well, it gave me a reason to learn more about using Git. I didn't quite got to the point where I can check out an old version. Everything I was trying merged an old version with my current working files. But that's for a different question...perhaps on programmers.SE.

Comment: I believe I solved this problem by checking some casts that occurred during constructor calls. If anyone needs more details when encountering a similar issue, please post a comment, and I'll be glad to provide them.